# Create a list of ip addresses and their matching netmasks from hostvars (not static inventory)

Tags: ansible, jinja2

When running a playbook, it's easy enough to get all ip addresses with `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` , later in the hostvars it's also easy to find the netmask assigned to each interface, e.g:

```
        "ansible_eth0": {
            "active": true,
            "device": "eth0",
            "ipv4": {
                "address": "192.168.1.100",
                "broadcast": "192.168.54.255",
                "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
                "network": "192.168.1.0"
```

I am trying to assemble a list of CIDRs:

```
192.168.100.1.0/24
172.16.20.0.0/16
```

Of all interfaces that the host has attached. (Without erroring out by specifying a limit, meaning if there is no `eth4`, then don't look for it).

It's surprisingly not straight forward as I thought it would be. I've tried with different jinja2 filters but I cannot assemble a proper, iterable list.

Thank you.

Comment: Use [Converting subnet masks to CIDR notation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html#converting-subnet-masks-to-cidr-notation). If you have a problem make it [mre].

Comment: Thank you, the usage of `ipaddr()`  - I'm familiar with. My issue is with actually gathering the _initial_ list, in order to run it through the `ipaddr()` filter. The link you've provided discusses a single, easily obtainable ip address. I am referring to gathering all ip address of the current host in play, along with their matching subnet masks - into an iterable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```yaml
- set_fact:
    cidr: "{{ cidr|default([]) +
              [(item.network ~ '/' ~ item.netmask)|ipaddr('network/prefix')] }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_interfaces|
            map('extract', ansible_facts, 'ipv4')|
            select('defined')|list }}"
```

Comment: Thank you, this does and beautifully so. I'm unable to ++ your rep due to my lack of rep :( .

Comment: I just got some rep up from another question, so was able to upvote :) Thank you again.